# Updated selenium, remote web element no longer works

Tags: c#, selenium, geckodriver

I had to update selenium from 2.53.1 to 3.0 today which also requires geckodriver.  I got everything installed okay however whenever I run my tests I am unable to fine any remote elements through all suites.  If I downgrade it works if I upgrade to the latest version of selenium it still doesn't work.  Anyone know of a workaround to finding remote elements? I'm currently doing so like below:

```
RemoteWebElement currentEventCell = (RemoteWebElement)gridElement.FindElements(By.CssSelector("tr[data-recordindex=\"" + RowIndex + "\"] td:nth-child(" + colIndex + ")"))[0];
var ScrollIt = currentEventCell.LocationOnScreenOnceScrolledIntoView;
```

The produced error

> threw exception:
>   OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException: Could not find element by: By.CssSelector: input[name="FunctionRoomOptionNumber"]

Comment: Can you confirm exactly which version of Selenium you are using now? Is it Selenium 3.4.0?

Answer (score 0):

From your code I can observe that you are trying to access Grid element.

So, here is the update:

Selenium 3.4.0-Java:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3946

Selenium 3.4.0-C#:https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3939

Remote WebDriver instance in c# nuget version 3.4.0 https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3929

Hope this info will help you :)